# Notepad++ | Copy with Syntax Highlighting but Preserve Dark Theme Palette

Tags: format, notepad++, clipboard

Edit: updating the original question for better clarity as I had initially not understood why and where the problem was occurring. So here's an accurate, revised explanation of the issue.

When you use a dark theme in both NPP and MS Word, an unusual interaction occurs which makes syntax-highlighted exports difficult to read in Word. The colour palette is applied in Notepad++ where it' clearly legible. Since the background is dark, standard and highlighted text colours are correspondingly light.

When you create an RTF export using 'right-click > Plugin commands > Copy text with Syntax Highlighting' the colours are copied to the clipboard "as is", meaning how you see them on your screen.

However, when Word is configured to use the dark theme in its display settings, it applies an automatic inversion on the black/white balance of any colours applied directly or indirectly, such as pasting RTF content into the document. This is usually a good feature which promotes legibility and means you don't need to manually adjust colours for everything when using this dark theme.

But a consequence of this system is that, when you paste the syntax-highlighted text that was already shaded appropriately for a dark background, this correspondingly flips the black/white levels towards the other side and ultimately leaves you with much darker shades of colours in all the text, making it hard to see clearly.

After trying out various approaches to solve the issue, I finally figured out how to bypass this colour correction. Please see below for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out! Updating for posterity in case anyone ever stumbles across this while searching for a solution to this specific problem.

Paste the code into a Text Box and apply a dark fill inside of it. This will bypass Word's automatic black/white adjustments that apply when the dark theme is enabled and your syntax highlights will once again stand out clearly and visibly as they did in Notepad++.

I couldn't tell you if the reason this works is that the rules just don't apply to text inside of a Text Box or if this is somehow the result the Text Box trying to apply a similar "invert" (and correspondingly cancelling the default one).

But in any case, I hope this is ends being useful to someone one day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).